# How to create the library that works with Vue 2.7 and Vue 3 simultaneously?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vite

First of all, there is [`vue-demi`](https://github.com/vueuse/vue-demi) library that give the possibility to create an universal libraries for Vue 2 and Vue 3.

But Evan You wrote [the strange passage](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html) in the Vue 2.7 release notes:

> We would also like to express our appreciation towards prior community efforts that bridged the gap before 2.7 was available:
>
> - @vue/composition-api plugin by @liximomo
> - vue-demi by @antfu
> - vite-plugin-vue2 by @underfin

It sounds like `vue-demi` is not actual anymore, is that true?

If it's true, then why I should use `@vitejs/plugin-vue` for Vue 3 and `@vitejs/plugin-vue2` for Vue 2.7? How can I create the universal library in this case?

Answer (score 0):

`vue-demi` is less necessary than it was before 2.7 came out, but it is still relevant if you want to create a truly universal library that will work on all versions of Vue 2, not just 2.7. Many users haven't and will not upgrade from 2.6 to 2.7. Also, `vue-demi` still provides some extra compatibility functionality. From the `vue-demi` [README](https://github.com/vueuse/vue-demi):

> <=2.6: exports from vue + @vue/composition-api with plugin auto installing.
>
> 2.7: exports from vue (Composition API is built-in in Vue 2.7).
>
> >=3.0: exports from vue, with polyfill of Vue 2's set and del API.

Regarding your question about `@vitejs/plugin-vue` and `@vitejs/plugin-vue2`, you seem to have confused Vite libraries with Vue libraries. Vite provides the functionality to actually run and compile Vue, and since Vue 2 and Vue 3 fundamentally run differently, Vite definitely needs 2 different libraries to support each one. If you are authoring a library that can be run *within* a Vue app, you may want to take advantage of `vue-demi` to ensure maximum compatibility.

Comment: Well, do I still need to create two packages / versions for Vue 2.7 and Vue 3?

Comment: No, and if you had been using vue-demi, you could have created a single package even before 2.7 came out. The entire purpose of vue-demi is so that you shouldn't have to create multiple packages. You seem to be misunderstanding this topic - maybe the vue-demi introductory blog post will help you out. https://antfu.me/posts/make-libraries-working-with-vue-2-and-3

Comment: I don't get one thing. If I don't use `vue-demi`, how to create a single package if I should use `@vitejs/plugin-vue` for Vue 3 and `@vitejs/plugin-vue2` for Vue 2.7?

Comment: Like I said, you seem to be mixing up Vite and Vue. Vite is there to run your app. If you are producing a library, there is no app. Of course, you'll be running an app during development that imports the main file from your library, but once you build your library, the app is stripped away and all that is left is your library code. The library should have a peer dependency of Vue, which means that the consuming app needs to provide a version of Vue that the library can get its proper `import`s from.

Comment: But Vite is used to build the library. Or `@vitejs/plugin-vue` and `@vitejs/plugin-vue2` produces the same build?

Comment: Yes, they produce essentially the same builds. Vite is actually using rollup to build the library; I don't know the specific details of how it works but I believe that `@vitejs/plugin-vue` is used only to help rollup understand how to compile the SFC's.

Comment: I will give a try. Thank you. I'll be back.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It writes: `The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=6ca0b798' does not provide an export named 'Fragment'`.

Comment: That's because it adds the following line to the compiled library:
`import { defineComponent, openBlock, createElementBlock, renderSlot, resolveComponent, normalizeClass, createVNode, withCtx, createBlock, createElementVNode, Fragment, renderList, resolveDynamicComponent, computed, reactive, normalizeStyle, withModifiers, createCommentVNode, ref, mergeProps, toHandlers, watchEffect, unref, watch, onMounted, onUnmounted } from "vue";`

Comment: It looks that `v-for` directive produces `Fragment` blocks when you build SFC with `@vitejs/plugin-vue`.

Comment: Please see the end of this article. https://alvarosaburido.dev/blog/how-to-create-an-universal-library-for-vue-2-3#:~:text=Of%20course%2C%20is%20not%20all%20roses If you're getting stuck, you should probably ask a new question, since this discussion has diverged from the original question and this is not my area of expertise.